# How do I print each iteration on separate lines in python3?

Tags: python, loops, printing

New to coding, a student and I am trying to get this output:

```
    Line 1: input from user
              
    Line 2: input from user
                
    Line 3: input from user
                
    Line 4:input from user

    etc.
```

here is my code

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enfYn.png)

Right now it only prints the last iteration entered into the loop, I need it to print each iteration on separate lines at the end of the loop no matter how many times it loops.

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not as an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you were printing `addLine` which came from a `while` loop, it would only print the last input before breaking the `while` loop. To fix this, change `addLine` to a list and then add all the inputs to the list each time. Then, after breaking the `while` loop, put the code inside a `for` loop so that it prints for each item in the list `addLine`. The `for` loop needs to be for every number in `counter`, starting at 0. For example if you entered 5 inputs then it would run from 0-4, so print the line and then the number which is `counter+1` so it does 1-5 instead of 0-4. Then just add `addLine[num]` so that it gets the correct item from the list.

```
userInput = ''
counter = 0
addLine = []
lineNumber = 0
newLine = ''

while True:
    userInput = input('Would you like to enter more lines?: ')

    if userInput == 'yes':
        addLine.append(input('Please enter your line: '))
        counter += 1
    elif userInput == 'no': 
        break

print('Verse')
for num in range(counter):
    print('Line ' + str(num + 1) + ': ' + addLine[num])
```

After some testing, this should work.

Comment: Thank you very much this works exactly how I needed it to, is there no other simple way to do this? As this was not covered in class at all. I thought about trying range as that seemed like it was what I needed but thought since it was not covered yet there was another way.

Comment: @manchild Np, as far as I know there isn't a simpler way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your print statement inside the loop:

```py
while True:
   ...
   print(f"Line {counter}: {addLine}")
```

Comment: Still only prints the last iteration entered.

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked your code a little:

```
user_input = ''
add_line = []

while True:
    user_input = input('Would you like to enter new lines?: ')

    if user_input == 'yes':
        add_line.append(input('Please enter your line: '))
    
    if user_input == 'no':
        break

print('Verse')
for i in add_line:
    print(f'Line {add_line.index(i) + 1}: {i}')
```

Test run:

```
Would you like to enter new lines?: yes
Please enter your line: this is a line
Would you like to enter new lines?: yes
Please enter your line: another line
Would you like to enter new lines?: no
Verse
Line 1: this is a line
Line 2: another line
```

Comment: This also works well too thank you for your help!

Comment: @Manchild np :)